# Can an app delay or turn off another app's alarm?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

I want my app to check the weather and when it's rainy to cancel my outdoor alarm. I'd rather my app delay or turn off the outdoor alarm that I set in Android's Clock app rather than reinvent an alarm app just for this extended logic. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that possible?

The answer is no, for obvious security reasons. You can't modify an alarm (where *alarm* means some action scheduled using the `AlarmManager`) set by some other application.

You might access the `AlarmClock` API as mentioned in the other answer, though
 most of those APIs are available starting with SDK 23 (Marshmallow)

Answer (score 1):

Android provides an AlarmClock API that lets you DISMISS or SNOOZE an alarm clock set by the Clock application. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html#ACTION_SNOOZE_ALARM

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to reinvent an alarm clock. Just implement a service to check whether it is raining and cancel the outdoor alarm if it isn't.